# JSON object truncated Mlab?

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I am using mlab for cloud database and I have like really long document. When I try to push those documents using mongoimport from mac terminal it goes in through perfectly, but when I check those documents in mlab portal after showing some portions of document it shows as **"JSON Object truncated"**. I don't know why this happens? Does it has anything to do with the type of subscription? Becasue I am using sandbox free. Does mllab is having any fixed size of document?

[image]

Please refer this image and let me know if you know how to fix any such issues. Please make sure my data is really huge and also let me know if I should think about any other alternative of mlab then which is best.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try retrieving the document using mongo shell or Robo Mongo (GUI)?

Comment: I am using MongoDB compass and in that I just checked it shows all complete data. NO TRUNCATION. Why? Such variation is there?

Comment: It looks like, mlab truncates the json document only for display purpose, the actual data is not truncated.

Comment: So, I’m making nodejs app and I’m using mongoose for CRUD, so there should not be any issue right?

Comment: No, there should not be any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after few discussions and checking on mongodb GUI app like Compass I just found that mlab truncates only gor viewing purpose. But actually if you check there is no truncation of complete object or document. So, we can do any number of CRUD operation and it ust work fine.